# Is there an Apache2 directive to explicitly set directory listings 403 Forbidden?

Tags: apache-2.4

Is there a directive to explicitly set directory listings *without an index file* to 403 Forbidden? The default behavior returns a 404 because [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) can't find the index file.

I don't have [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) loaded and `Options` are set to just `FollowSymLinks`. I tried `-Indexes`, but that still returned a 404.

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    DirectorySlash On
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I shouldn't matter, but I'm using Apache 2.4.

Comment: Im using Apache/2.4.6 on some servers and have set **Options -Indexes** and Dirs whitout index file return a 403, but if directory does not exist apache return a 404,
maybe you are trying to access a nonexistent folder ?

Comment: Interesting. No, the dir really exists. Even `DirectorySlash` is 301'ing me to the 404. Very strange. Do you have any mod_rewrite rules forbidding dir listings?

Comment: Is there a reason you need this 403 return?

Comment: @jeff on some server I only put a .htaccess whit a options -Indexes on /home and all accounts (/home/user1 /home/user2 etc ) automaticly get a 403 error on dirs whitout index file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question after a lot of trial and error. This answer should apply to Apache >= 2.0.

In summary, it seems the `Indexes` option for the `Options` directive requires [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html). You can stop reading now unless you'd like more info on the default Apache behavior.

**More Info**

The key is whether or not [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) is loaded. If it's not loaded, setting `Options -Indexes` will have no effect and return a 404, which makes sense because the mod_dir `DirectoryIndex` directive can't find your index file. If it is loaded, setting `Options -Indexes` will return a 403.

This is somewhat explained in the [Apache Options docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options) under *Indexes*, which is a little confusing because `Options` is a part of mod_core.

> **Indexes**
>
> If a URL which maps to a directory is requested, and there is no
>   DirectoryIndex (e.g., index.html) in that directory, then
>   mod_autoindex will return a formatted listing of the directory.

... and explained on the [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) page:

> Automatic index generation is enabled with using Options +Indexes. See
>   the Options directive for more details.

My tests indicate that enabling/disabling .htaccess files with `AllowOverride` is irrelevant.